# Covergence of sequence of sum of M Cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf, trigonometric-series

I have been working on [the original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687052/absolute-summability-of-summation-of-integer-exponents-of-polynomial-roots-bibo)
and have narrowed it down to proving that :

$\displaystyle lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)$ does not exist (or if exists, is not equal to 0) ,$\forall d_{i}$ & $\theta_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ ,$k_{i} \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$, $M \in \mathbb{N}\geq {2}$

Given : $\theta _{i}$ are independent in the sense that $a\cos\left(n\theta_{i1}+\phi_{1}\right)+b\cos\left(n\theta_{i2}+\phi_{2}\right)$ cannot be expressed in terms of $c\cos\left(n\gamma+\phi\right)$

Intuitively it makes sense because all the cosines will oscillate and hence their linear combination is also supposed to oscillate but **how do I prove this rigorously?**

---

Some efforts :
If the limit exists and equal to $L$ then $\displaystyle lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos \left(p\theta_{i}\right)\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)$ is also equal to $L$ , $\forall p \in \mathbb{N}$
this can be obtained by just changing the variable $n\to n+2p$ and adding with the original limit. We can repeat the process $r$ times to obtain product of $r$ such cosines in front of each summation term. But I don't see where I am going with this.

Comment: To me it seems that if $\forall i: \theta_i=0, d_i=\pi/2$, then each term is zero for each $n$, so the whole series convergers to 0. If we just have $\forall i: \theta_i=0$, then the terms are not dependent on $n$, so we have sum of fixed terms that certainly can be 0. If the $\theta_i$ are multiples of $2\pi$, then the terms also do not depend on $n$, so the sum could also be 0. 

I've looked at the original problem, but can't immediatly see the connection, so can't say if my counterexamples can occur or not.

Comment: @lngix Sorry. I should have mentioned that $\theta _{i}$ are independent in the sense that $a\cos\left(n\theta_{i}+\phi_{1}\right)+b\cos\left(n\theta_{j}+\phi_{2}\right)$ cannot be expressed in terms of $c\cos\left(n\gamma+\phi\right)$

Comment: @lngix you've found out a fundamental flaw in my positing of the question. Thanks. I should have mentioned that simultaneously the corresponding sin sequence also don't have a zero limit. Because $M=1$ and $\theta= 2p\pi$ , $d=\frac {\pi} {2}$ acts as a counterexample.

Comment: As I have solved the problem, so I think I'll leave it at that

Comment: Nice you found a solution!

Comment: @lngix It is!! Can you please go through my answer and verify it?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer :**  I am not well versed with Mathematics so please point out the faults, in the comments. I'll be  highly obliged.

---

Let the limit exists and be equal to $L$

Let $q=n-2$

So,
$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{i}\end {equation}$
$\displaystyle \begin{equation}\Rightarrow  L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\left(\left(q+2\right)\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\end{equation}$

$n\to \infty \Rightarrow n-2\to\infty\Rightarrow q\to \infty$
$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  L=lim_{q \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\left(\left(q+2\right)\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)$

Replacing the dummy variable, 
$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\left(\left(n+2\right)\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{ii}\end {equation}$

Adding (ii) && (i),
$\displaystyle \begin {equation}2L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\left[\cos\left(\left(n+2\right)\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)+\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right]\right)\end {equation}$
Using $\begin{equation}\cos a +\cos b = 2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\end{equation}$,

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\theta_{i}\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\end {equation}$

Replacing $r=n+1$ and re-replacing $r=n$,

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{M}\left(k_{i}\cos\theta_{i}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{iii}\end {equation}$

Multiplying (i) by $\cos\theta_{1}$ and subtracting it from (iii),

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L\left(1-\cos\theta_{1}\right)=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=2}^{M}\left(k_{i}\left(\cos\theta_{i}-\cos\theta_{1}\right)\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{iv}\end {equation}$

Now replacing $L\left(1-\cos\theta_{1}\right)$ by $L1$ and $k_{i}\left(\cos\theta_{i}-\cos\theta_{1}\right)$ by $k_{i1}$,

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L1=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=2}^{M}\left(k_{i1}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{v}\end {equation}$

As the algorithm to transform $\left(i\right)\to\left(v\right)$ did not assume any limitation on the values of $k_{i}$,thus same algorithm could be applied to transform $\left(v\right)\to\left(vi\right)$,

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L2=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=3}^{M}\left(k_{i2}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{vi}\end {equation}$where $L2=L1\left(1-\cos\theta_{2}\right)$ and $k_{i2}=k_{i1}\left(\cos\theta_{i}-\cos\theta_{2}\right)$

So it follows that $L_{j}=L_{j-1}\left(1-\cos\theta_{j}\right)$ and $k_{ij}=k_{i j-1}\left(\cos\theta_{i}-\cos\theta_{j}\right)$

By repeating the transformations, we have :

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L_{M-1}=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=M}^{M}\left(k_{i M-1}\cos\left(n\theta_{i}-d_{i}\right)\right)\tag{vii}\end {equation}$

Now, $k_{M M-1} = \prod_{i=1}^{M-1}\left(\cos\theta_{M}-\cos\theta_{i}\right) \neq 0$,
as $\theta_{i}$ are independent

Let $L_{F}=\frac{L_{M-1}}{k_{M M-1}}$,
Using (vii) :

$\displaystyle \begin {equation}L_{F}=lim_{n \to \infty} \cos\left(n\theta_{M}-d_{M}\right)\tag{viii}\end {equation}$

As $M\geq2$, we can always choose $\theta_{M}\neq 2p\pi$, $p\in\mathbb{N}$

But equation (viii) is incorrect (because such a limit cannot exist$^{1}$) hence by contradiction equation (i) is incorrect or such a limit does not exist.

Thus proved.

---

1 : I think that's the weakest point of the proof?